# Android - TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzblr.class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I am trying to execute my firebase based application which is giving me following error
Update 1- I Updated `multiDexEnabled` to `true` also included `packagingOptions` but getting this error:

error log - `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
-> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzblr.class`

My app-level build.gradle:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.multiplexerx.smartjournal"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
buildTypes {

    release {
        minifyEnabled  true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}




dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.github.chyrta:AndroidOnboarder:0.7'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes sure that you're using the same library version for all of Firebase (and play services):

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.1'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.1'
```